# Iterating through a List<List<>> looking for a value in F#

Tags: c#, list, syntax, f#, foreach

I have a `List<List<int>>` in F#. I need to iterate through it looking for a given value `val`.
In C# I would do something like:

```
public bool contains(List<List<int>> list, int value)
    foreach (l in list ){
        foreach(val in l){
             if (val == value)
                 return true; //found value
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I'm looking for the equivalent in F#. I tried the following but I'm doing something wrong, because I'm not still used to F# syntax:

```
type foo = 
    {
     l : List<List<float>>

    }

let contains (value: float) : bool = 
   for row in foo.l do
       for val in row do
            if (val == value)
                true
   false
```

The code above is wrong.

Could anyone suggest me how to achieve that result?

Comment: Btw, even in C#, you can just do `list.SelectMany(l => l).Contains(value)`

Comment: @Ani: oh..good to know. I'm coming from Java and I still ignore a lot of C# features..

Comment: @Ani: for what concern pad's answer, do you know how to break the iteration once found the value?

Comment: FYI you can also write that code in C# as `(from item in list from val in item where val == value select val).Any()`

Comment: @EricLippert or `list.Any(el => el.Any(val == value))`, or...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a direct translation of your C# code:

```
   let contains value (ls: _ list list) = 
       let mutable found = false
       for row in ls do
           if not found then
               for el in row do
                    if not found && el = value then
                        found <- true
       found
```

To modify value of a variable in F#, you should use `mutable` or `ref` keywords. However, in F# doing the functional way:

```
let contains value ls  = 
     ls |> List.exists (List.exists ((=) value))
```

Different from `for .. in ... do`, which is a syntactic sugar, the higher-order function `List.exists` will stop immediately when it finds the answer. <strike>This version does not scale well if your lists are big. You can convert list to set to be able to find the element faster:</strike>

```
let contains value (ls: _ list list) = 
     ls |> List.concat |> Set.ofList |> Set.contains value
```

Comment: +1: I tried something similar but I was missing '<-' . Do you know if it is possible to break the iteration when the value is found? just to avoid unuseful cycles..

Comment: wow..thank you so much. that's very helpful even if know I should study the syntax you have used. Btw, In my real application I have a List<List<AType>> so I don't think I can use Set.contains on records..

Comment: do you have a link to any document explaining the syntax you used in your last 2 examples?

Comment: Try to look at high-order functions on `List` module (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233224.aspx), and it should be similar with `Set`

Comment: @pad: not likely converting List to Set can speed up things as fast find will be spoiled by slow conversion itself. Make sense only for scenario "one conversion multiple searches".

Comment: @Heisenbug: You can use `Set.contains` on record types in F#.

Answer (score 9):

Another, slightly different, way to do it

```
let contains value items =
  items
  |> Seq.concat
  |> Seq.exists ((=) value)
```

or, more concisely

```
let contains value = 
  Seq.concat >> Seq.exists ((=) value)
```